# How can i get the index of a particular subview when user tap on it inside tableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift

i have a table view which has multiple section 
i want to know the indexPath when user tapped on itemImage.

```
class ItemCell:UITableViewCell{
   @IBOutlet weak var itemImage:UIImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var itemName:UILabel!

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass your ItemImage and TableView instance in this function

```
func viewIndexPath(subView:UIView , tableView:UITableView)->IndexPath?{
     let subViewPosition = subView.convert(subView.frame ,to:tableView)
     if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(at:subViewPosition){
        return indexPath
     }

   return nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `cellForRow`, add click action to your `UIImageView` and pass the tapGestureRecognizer, which is used to get the tapped image view in click handler function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! ItemCell

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    cell.itemImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.itemImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    return cell
}
```

Then in your handler function, you can get your image view. So your image view is located in the content view, which is then located in the cell. So you can get the cell by calling `parent`, and then further get the `indexPath`

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tappedImage = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
    if let cell = tappedImage.superview?.superview as? ItemCell{
        let indexPath = self.YourTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    }
    //... other code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i will give only row number but i want to know in which section of row user tapped on it

Comment: @Jhon Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add a `delegate`  to your `cell` and create a `protocol`  inside the cell like so

```
protocol ItemCellProtocol {
    func didSelectCell(cell: ItemCell)
}
```

Your `viewController`  with the `tableView` inside it should confirm to this `protocol`  and implement this method.

Add

```
 var delegate: ItemCellProtocol?
```

To `ItemCell`

Everytime you `dequeue` a `ItemCell` set the `delegate` property to `self`.

Then inside your `cell` add a method for listening for the `imageTapped`

```
func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {  { 
    delegate?.didSelectCell(self)
}
```

This will fire your method in the `viewController`  and pass a reference of an item cell to it inside that method just call `indexPathForCell` method on the table view and you'll have the `indexPath`